# Detect what element was clicked with JAVA

Tags: java, html, selenium, browser, automation

For the project in my school I am creating a automation tool for the web with JAVA.
This tool should detect the user activity on web page, save it, and then run the result as Tests.

I found solution for the running part: I will use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to run all the tests that I am automatically generating.

But I did not found how to detect user activity on the web, Selenium can do it? 
The Idea is to check what element the user was clicked, hover, send keys...

There is a way do detect what element was clicked in the browser with pure JAVA? if not, there is some tool to check it?

Comment: Generally either those elements would be something like links and form-submit buttons, or you'd have JavaScript event handlers attached to them.

Comment: There is no "Java" executed in the browser, so no, it's not possible. Java normally runs in the backend of your application and the backend is not supposed to know about the components in the UI. Did you mean javascript instead of Java?

Comment: do you want a video recording kind of thing which record all your action performed by selenium script?

Comment: You can use event handler with selenium for certain actions like browsing url, after click, before click etc, see the link: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [Selenium IDE plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) for Firefox. It will help record your usage of a website. You can then reuse the scenario to perform your test.

Since the tests are actually made on the front-end, the tests are not tied to Java. Your back-end could be written in C# or PHP: the front-end user has no idea what's behind.

Comment: If you don't like the answer make you add a comment to clarify what is not understood.